# Does ExoPlayer or AVFoundation work with an udpxy stream?

Tags: flutter, http, avfoundation, exoplayer

I'm building a frontend for a proprietary IPTV backend, which receives its channel streams via multicast, then for the end users it uses udpxy to convert the traffic from multicast to HTTP. However, neither ExoPlayer or AVFoundation seem to accept this stream (both the VLC app & `flutter_vlc_player` play this stream nicely) - I'm using the `video_player` plugin for Flutter, so I may miss over some live stream specific impls. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Media information (VLC):
[image]

udpxy: `udpxy 1.0-23.12 (prod) standard [Linux 5.10.0-10-amd64 x86_64]`, the output stream is `application/octet-stream` (maybe that can cause some problems?)

Comment: You need to mention what you want to do, your questions seem to state that you have converted the multicast stream to an HTTP response stream successfully already, so I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: If you would have read the question, you would see that the HTTP stream is not the problem (atleast not the problem I'm trying to (or can) fix). I need to play this stream.